# Collection View Text Field textFieldDidEndEditing when CollectionView Scrolled

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a Collection View that is a custom layout.  It contains text fields that users can update and it will save to an array.  The text fields take up the entire collection view cells , basically it looks like Microsoft Excel etc and scrolls horizontal and vertical.

The problem is if you enter a number in a text field and scroll the collection view without hitting return, the cell is dequeued and the index path becomes null.

I would like the text field to end editing if the collection view is scrolled.

Here is the code I use for the textFieldDidEndEditing.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
UICollectionViewCell *selectedCell = (UICollectionViewCell *)[[textField superview] superview];
UICollectionView *collectionViewForSelection = (UICollectionView *)[selectedCell superview];
NSIndexPath *textFieldIndexPath = [collectionViewForSelection indexPathForCell:selectedCell];

if (textFieldIndexPath != NULL) {
[[_collectionArray objectAtIndex:textFieldIndexPath.section] replaceObjectAtIndex:textFieldIndexPath.row withObject:textField.text];
[self saveArray];
}
}
```

I have tried without any luck and I didn't post any code from my attempts.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you can try to call the resignFirstResponder of the active text field in the delegate scrollViewDidScroll:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    //resign the first responder of the active text field
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Since you have a lot of text fields in the view, you can call the [endEditing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) in the view itself:

> **endEditing:**
>
> Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the
>   first responder status.